# gensim Doc2Vec: Getting from txt files to TaggedDocuments

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

Beginner here.

I have a large body of .txt files that I want to train a Doc2Vec model on. However, I am having trouble importing the data into python in a usable way.

To import data, I have used:

```
docLabels = []
docLabels = [f for f in listdir(“PATH TO YOU DOCUMENT FOLDER”) if 
f.endswith(‘.txt’)]
data = []
for doc in docLabels:
    data.append(open(‘PATH TO YOU DOCUMENT FOLDER’ + doc).read()) `
```

However, with this, I get a "list", which I can do no further work with. I cannot seem to find how to import text files in a way they can be used with NLTK / doc2vec anywhere on SO or in tutorials.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only addressing the portion of the question indicated by the title, about `Doc2Vec` and `TaggedDocument`. (NLTK is a separate matter.)

The `TaggedDocument` class requires you to specify `words` and `tags` for each object created.

So where you are currently just appending a big full-read of the file to your `data`, you will instead want to:

- break that data into words – one super-simple way is to just `.split()` it on whitespace, though most project do more
- decide on a tag or tags, perhaps just the filename itself
- instantiate a `TaggedDocument`, and append that to `data`

So, you could replace your existing loop with:

```
for doc in docLabels:
    words = open(open(‘PATH TO YOU DOCUMENT FOLDER’ + doc).read()).split()
    tags = [doc]
    data.append(TaggedDocument(words=words, tags=tags)
```

Comment: Hi gojomo, thanks, that worked! One further question: Do I understand correctly that if i want to "preprocess" my text (e.g., lowercase, stem, remove stopwords, etc.), it would be ideal to do this before I create a TaggedDocument? --- And if so, is it advisable to add this to the "for doc in docLabels" loop, e.g., words = as above, then words = words.lower(); etc.?

Comment: There's many reasonable ways/places to do such preprocessing. Note that much published word2vec/doc2vec work doesn't remove stop-words or stem, & often even retains punctuation as tokens – so it's not strictly necessary. If/when your corpus becomes large, you'd eventually not want to create all `TaggedDocuments` in an in-memory list, but rather stream them from a file as a Python iterable-object. In that case, you *could* preprocess on each read, or do the preprocessing separately once & write-to-disk the preprocessed text (to save from repeating on each re-iteration).